# Error with componentDid mount when setting value from api call response

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a `disableButton: boolean;` and want to set it's value based on the response from this `GET`:

```
async getDocStatus(policy: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return await ApiService.getData(this.apiUrl + policy + this.myEndpoint).then(
        (response) => response.data
    );
}
```

I'd like this to be done when my page loads so have added the call to my `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
   const queryString = require('query-string');
   const parsed = queryString.parse(location.search);
   return this.reissueCertService.getDocStatus(parsed.pol).then(response => {
      this.setState({disableButton: response});
   }).catch((error) => {
         this.loggingService.logError('Error returning Docs ' + error);
   });
}
```

My problem is that when I load my page I get this error and I'm not really sure what it's telling me or how to fix it. Can anybody advise?

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getDocStatus')
> CertificateDisclaimer../src/components/certificate/Certificate.tsx.Certificate.componentDidMount
> C:/git/ui.myui/src/components/certificate/Certificate.tsx:38
> 35 | componentDidMount() {
> 36 |     const queryString = require('query-string');
> 37 |     const parsed = queryString.parse(location.search);
> 38 |     this.reissueService.getDocStatus(parsed.policy).then(response => {
> 40 |        this.setState({disableButton: response});
> 41 |     }).catch((error) => {
> View compiled
> ▼ 19 stack frames were expanded.
> commitLifeCycles
> C:/git/ui.myui/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19814
> commitLayoutEffects
> C:/git/ui.myui/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22803
> HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
> C:/git/ui.myui/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:188
> invokeGuardedCallbackDev
> C:/git/ui.myui/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:237
> invokeGuardedCallback
> C:/git/ui.myui/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:292
> commitRootImpl
> C:/git/ui.myui/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22541
> unstable_runWithPriority
> C:/git/ui.myui/node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:653
> runWithPriority$1
> C:/git/ui.myui/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11039
> commitRoot
> C:/git/ui.myui/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22381
> finishSyncRender
> C:/git/ui.myui/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21807
> performSyncWorkOnRoot
> C:/git/ui.myui/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21793
> (anonymous function)
> C:/git/ui.myui/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11089
> unstable_runWithPriority
> C:/git/ui.myui/node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:653
> runWithPriority$1
> C:/git/ui.myui/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11039
> flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
> C:/git/ui.myui/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11084
> flushSyncCallbackQueue
> C:/git/ui.myui/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11072
> scheduleUpdateOnFiber
> C:/git/ui.myui/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21199
> enqueueSetState
> C:/git/ui.myui/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12639
> Document../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState
> C:/git/ui.myui/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:471
> ▲ 19 stack frames were expanded.
> (anonymous function)
> C:/git/ui.myui/src/containers/document/Document.tsx:37
> 34 | const queryString = require('query-string');
> 35 | const parsed = queryString.parse(location.search);
> 36 | return this.listingService.getDocs(parsed.policy).then(docs => {
> 37 |     this.setState({ isLoading: false, docs });
> 38 |     return docs;
> 39 | }).catch((error) => {
> 40 |     this.loggingService.logError('Error returning Docs ' + error);
> View compiled
> This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
> Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.

This is my component class:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './Certificate.css';
import { PackRow } from '../../services/DocService/DocService';
import { LoggingService } from '../../services/logging/LoggingService';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import crypto from 'crypto';
import { Reissue } from '../reissue/Reissue';
import { Button } from '@digital/react-avis-atom';
import { ReissueService } from 'src/services/ReissueService/ReissueService';

interface Props {
  pol: string;
  triggerReload: () => void;
  packs: PackRow[];
}

interface State {
   disableButton: boolean;
   showPrompt: boolean;
}

export class Certificate extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  loggingService: LoggingService;
  reissueCertService: ReissueService;

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.loggingService = new LoggingService();
    this.state = {
      disableButton: false,
      showPrompt: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      const queryString = require('query-string');
      const parsed = queryString.parse(location.search);
      return this.reissueCertService.getDocStatus(parsed.pol).then(response => {
         this.setState({disableButton: response});
      }).catch((error) => {
          this.loggingService.logError('Error returning Docs ' + error);
      });
  }

  onAgreement = (pol: string) => () => {
    if (this.consentGiven(this.props.pol)) {
       return;
    }

    this.loggingService.logCertAndDiscAgreement(
      'Uploading cert and disc agreement',
      pol
    );
    
    let content = '';
    this.props.packs.forEach(pack => {
       pack.docDisplay.forEach(docRow => {
          if (docRow.docName === 'Certificate and Disc') {  
             content += this.getDocumentId(docRow.docUrl) + ';';
          }
       });
    });
    const ref = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(pol).digest('hex');
    Cookies.set('CONSENT_' + ref, content, { expires: 365,  path: '' });
    this.props.triggerReload();
  }
  
  consentGiven = (pol: string) => {
     const ref = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(pol).digest('hex');
     const consentedDocs = Cookies.get('CONSENT_' + ref) || null;
     if (consentedDocs === null) {
       return false;
     }
 
     let consent = true;
     this.props.packs.forEach(pack => {
        pack.docDisplay.forEach(docRow => {
        if (
           docRow.docName === 'Certificate and Disc'  
           && !consentedDocs.includes(this.getDocumentId(docRow.docUrl))) {
              consent = false;
           }
        });
     });
     return consent;         
  }
  
  certDiscCount = () => {
     let count = 0;
     this.props.packs.forEach(pack => {
        pack.docDisplay.forEach(docRow => {
           if (docRow.docName === 'Cert and Disc') {
              count++;
           }
        });
     });
     return count;       
  }
  
  getDocumentId = (docUrl: string) => {
     const docPath = docUrl.match(/\/documents\/(.+?)\//g);
     const docPathElements = docPath !== null ? docPath[0].split('/') : null;
     return docPathElements !== null && docPathElements.length > 3 ? docPathElements[2] : '';        
  }
  
  consentBox = (pol: string) => {
     return this.consentGiven(pol) ? 'consent-cell--agreement consent-cell--agreed' : 'consent-cell--agreement';
  }
 
  showReissue = () => {
   this.setState({ showPrompt: true });
  }
 
  hideReissue = () => {
   this.setState({ showPrompt: false });
  }
 
  disableButton = () => {
   this.setState({ disableButton: true });
  }

  render() {
    const { pol } = this.props;
    if (this.certDiscCount() === 0) {
       return ('');
    }

    return (
      <table className="consent-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colSpan={2}>
              <span>
                Details
              </span>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td className="consent-cell consent-cell--text">
              Your docs are available for
              download and print.<br/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <br />
          <tr>
             <td>
                <table className={this.consentBox(pol)}>
                   <tbody>
                      <tr>
                         <td className="consent-cell consent-cell--text">
                            <label>
                                <input 
                                  type="radio"
                                  checked={this.consentGiven(pol)} 
                                  onChange={this.onAgreement(pol)} 
                                />
                               &nbsp;&nbsp; Agree and access
                            </label>
                         </td>
                      </tr>
                   </tbody>
                </table>
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>
               <Button
                  onClick={this.showReissue}
                  primary={true}
                  fullWidth={false}
                  disabled={this.state.disableButton}
               >
                  If you cannot print in colour please click here
               </Button>
               <Reissue
                            handleClose={this.hideReissue} 
                            disableButton={this.disableButton}
                            showPrompt={this.state.showPrompt} 
                            pol={this.props.pol}
               />
             </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In this line `this.reissueCertService.getDocStatus` the value of `this.reissueCertService` is undefined, that's why you are getting this error. Can you provide the whole component class code here?

Comment: component class added now.

Comment: Its very obvious, `this.reissueCertService` is undefined. Also the async / await inside getDocStatus is unessecary

Comment: Thanks. Sorted now. Couldn't see the obvious. Maybe it's too early in the morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you missed setting up the component's `reissueCertService`.

```
constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.loggingService = new LoggingService();
    // add this line
    this.reissueCertService = new ReissueService();
    this.state = {
      disableButton: false,
      showPrompt: false
    };
  }
```